# Prevent scroll when open menu

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to use the apple style mobile menu on non-mobile larger screens.
The menu is part of several elements visible in the body and it does not cover the entire screen.

Is it possible to prevent scrolling when the menu is opened?

I know I could do that with

```
position: fixed;
overflow: hidden;
```

but not sure where to place them.

Michelle.

```js
(function(){
    var burger = document.querySelector('.burger-container'),
        header = document.querySelector('.header');
    
    burger.onclick = function() {
        header.classList.toggle('menu-opened');
    }
}());
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ek+Mukta:200);
body {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.4;
}

.window {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 567px;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 65px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: 0 0 65px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.window .header {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out, background 1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out, background 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
          transition-delay: 0.2s;
  z-index: 1;
}
.window .header .burger-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.window .header .burger-container #burger {
  width: 18px;
  height: 8px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: -4px auto 0;
  top: 50%;
}
.window .header .burger-container #burger .bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
          transition-delay: 0s;
}
.window .header .burger-container #burger .bar.topBar {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
          transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
}
.window .header .burger-container #burger .bar.btmBar {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
          transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
}
.window .header .icon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 22px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.window .header .icon.icon-bag {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
          transform: translateX(0px);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.65s;
          transition-delay: 0.65s;
}
.window .header ul.menu {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 48px 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  margin-top: 5px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-30px);
          transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-30px);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.49s;
          transition-delay: 0.49s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.42s;
          transition-delay: 0.42s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.35s;
          transition-delay: 0.35s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.28s;
          transition-delay: 0.28s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.21s;
          transition-delay: 0.21s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.14s;
          transition-delay: 0.14s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.07s;
          transition-delay: 0.07s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "Ek Mukta", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 2.35;
  font-weight: 200;
  width: 100%;
}
.window .header.menu-opened {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in, background 0.5s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in, background 0.5s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s;
          transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened .burger-container {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.window .header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
          transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.topBar {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
          transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
}
.window .header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.btmBar {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
          transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
          transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
  opacity: 1;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.27s;
          transition-delay: 0.27s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.34s;
          transition-delay: 0.34s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.41s;
          transition-delay: 0.41s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.48s;
          transition-delay: 0.48s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.55s;
          transition-delay: 0.55s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.62s;
          transition-delay: 0.62s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.69s;
          transition-delay: 0.69s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened .icon.icon-bag {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(75px);
          transform: translateX(75px);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
          transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.window .content {
  font-family: "Ek Mukta", sans-serif;
  padding: 67px 4% 0;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.window .content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.window .content h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.window .content img {
  width: 95%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 75px auto 75px;
}
.window .content img:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin: 75px auto;
}

.outside-text {
    width: 40%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.outside-text p {
    margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="window">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="burger-container">
      <div id="burger">
        <div class="bar topBar"></div>
        <div class="bar btmBar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon icon-apple"></div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Mac</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">iPad</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">TV</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Music</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="shop icon icon-bag"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content"> <img src="https://images.apple.com/v/ipad-air-2/c/images/overview/performance_large.png" alt=""/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outside-text">
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quiet sure if this is what you actually want. The following code prevent scrolling if the menu is opend!

```
if(header.getAttribute("class").indexOf("menu-opened") > -1)
    alert("opend"); // opend
else
    alert("closed"); // closed
```

Check if class contains menu-opened.

> **EDIT: As Sergey Khmelevskoy mentioned in his answere it is very usefull if you scroll to top once the menu is open.**

```js
(function(){
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],
        burger = document.querySelector('.burger-container'),
        header = document.querySelector('.header');
    
    burger.onclick = function() {
        header.classList.toggle('menu-opened');
        if(header.getAttribute("class").indexOf("menu-opened") > -1){
             body.classList.add("overflow_hidden");
             window.scrollTo(0, 0); // scroll to the top of the page
        }
        else 
             body .classList.remove("overflow_hidden");
    }
}());
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ek+Mukta:200);
body {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.4;
}
 
.overflow_hidden {
   overflow-y: hidden !important;
}

.window {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 567px;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 65px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: 0 0 65px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.window .header {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out, background 1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out, background 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
          transition-delay: 0.2s;
  z-index: 1;
}
.window .header .burger-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.window .header .burger-container #burger {
  width: 18px;
  height: 8px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: -4px auto 0;
  top: 50%;
}
.window .header .burger-container #burger .bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
          transition-delay: 0s;
}
.window .header .burger-container #burger .bar.topBar {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
          transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
}
.window .header .burger-container #burger .bar.btmBar {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
          transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
}
.window .header .icon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 22px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.window .header .icon.icon-bag {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
          transform: translateX(0px);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.65s;
          transition-delay: 0.65s;
}
.window .header ul.menu {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 48px 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  margin-top: 5px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-30px);
          transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-30px);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.49s;
          transition-delay: 0.49s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.42s;
          transition-delay: 0.42s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.35s;
          transition-delay: 0.35s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.28s;
          transition-delay: 0.28s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.21s;
          transition-delay: 0.21s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.14s;
          transition-delay: 0.14s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.07s;
          transition-delay: 0.07s;
}
.window .header ul.menu li.menu-item a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: "Ek Mukta", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 2.35;
  font-weight: 200;
  width: 100%;
}
.window .header.menu-opened {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in, background 0.5s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in, background 0.5s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s;
          transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened .burger-container {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.window .header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
          transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.topBar {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
          transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
}
.window .header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.btmBar {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
          transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
          transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
  opacity: 1;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.27s;
          transition-delay: 0.27s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.34s;
          transition-delay: 0.34s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.41s;
          transition-delay: 0.41s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.48s;
          transition-delay: 0.48s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.55s;
          transition-delay: 0.55s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.62s;
          transition-delay: 0.62s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.69s;
          transition-delay: 0.69s;
}
.window .header.menu-opened .icon.icon-bag {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(75px);
          transform: translateX(75px);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
          transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.window .content {
  font-family: "Ek Mukta", sans-serif;
  padding: 67px 4% 0;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.window .content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.window .content h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.window .content img {
  width: 95%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 75px auto 75px;
}
.window .content img:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin: 75px auto;
}

.outside-text {
    width: 40%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.outside-text p {
    margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="window">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="burger-container">
      <div id="burger">
        <div class="bar topBar"></div>
        <div class="bar btmBar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon icon-apple"></div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Mac</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">iPad</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">TV</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Music</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Support</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="shop icon icon-bag"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content"> <img src="https://images.apple.com/v/ipad-air-2/c/images/overview/performance_large.png" alt=""/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outside-text">
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I generally recommend javascript based solution instead of regular body `overflow: hidden` fix as page won't jump to the top when you open the menu somewhere in the middle of the page

```
 function preventDefault(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.preventDefault)
      e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;
  }

  var preventKeys = {
    37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1
  };

  function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
    if (preventKeys[e.keyCode]) {
      preventDefault(e);
      return false;
    }
  }

  function disableScroll() {
    var target = $('.page').get(0)
    if (window.addEventListener) // older FF
      target.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
    target.onwheel = preventDefault; // modern standard
    target.onmousewheel = target.onmousewheel = preventDefault; // older browsers, IE
    target.ontouchmove = preventDefault; // mobile
    target.onkeydown = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
  }

  function enableScroll() {
    var target = $('.page').get(0)
    if (window.removeEventListener)
      target.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
    target.onmousewheel = target.onmousewheel = null;
    target.onwheel = null;
    target.ontouchmove = null;
    target.onkeydown = null;
  }
```

The original idea is not mine, I found this on Stackoverflow long time ago and take this part from project to project. Unfortunately, I can't credit an author. Please let me know the topic in comments below if you know one

To keep overflow scrolling on the menu (if the height is greater than 100vh) you should make menu outside target `disableScroll()` / `enableScroll()` functions

i.e.

```
<body>
<div class="menu> .. menu .. </div>

<div class="page"> .. site content .. </div>
</body>
```